# mongodb 2d location search using java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm experiencing problems with java driver for mongodb. I need to find places withing specified radius. Query through shell works perfectly:

```
db.dealy.venues.find({point : { $near : [55.7503343916123,37.65418658056641] , $maxDistance : 80/111.12}})
```

But when I try to do the same through java driver, it gets empty result.

```
add(new BasicDBObject("point",
                    new BasicDBObject("$near", new Double[]{nearestLng, nearestLat}).append("$maxDistance", 80/111.12)));
```

Can someone explain me why? Thanks!

Comment: Because you used `.put()` rather than `.append()`

Comment: Looks correct to me. Maybe you should try again.